# Django "for" loop and python dictionary problems

Tags: python, django

I'm having a couple of issues getting django templating for loop tag to go through this dictionary:

It is definitely being passed to the page ok as if I just do:

```
{% for event in events %}
   {{ event }} 
{% endfor %}
```

it writes 1,2,3 but when I try and do {{ event.start }} it just doesn't output anything...

```
    evs = {

        "1": {
            'start': '8:00:00',
            'end': '9:00:00',
            'name': 'test',
            'description': 'test',
            'image_url': 'http://test',
            'channel_url': 'http://test',
        },

        "2": {
            'start': '8:00:00',
            'end': '9:00:00',
            'name': 'test',
            'description': 'test',
            'image_url': 'http://test',
            'channel_url': 'http://test',
        },

        "3": {
            'start': '8:00:00',
            'end': '9:00:00',
            'name': 'test',
            'description': 'test',
            'image_url': 'http://test',
            'channel_url': 'http://test',
        }

    }
```

And this is my django code in the template:

```
    {% for event in events %}
            {{ event.end }}
            {{ event.name }}
            {{ event.description }}
            {{ event.image_url }}
            {{ event.channel_url }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you are just iterating over `events` you are just iterating over the dictonary's keys; you need to iterate over the dictionary's values: `{% for event in events.values %}`!

Comment: @Ignacio: I don't believe your syntax would work.  It's the equivalent of events['event'].start

Comment: The syntax crashes my code. However, {% for key, event in events.items %} does not work either but doesnt crash my code. Why am I not able to print {{event}} to the page?

Answer (score 5):

Well, in your case, `event` is the always the key of one entry (which is a string), not the object itself, so `event.start` cannot work.

Have look at the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for). You could do:

```
{% for key, event in events.items %}
        {{ event.end }}
        {{ event.name }}
        {{ event.description }}
        {{ event.image_url }}
        {{ event.channel_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If events is a dictionary, this syntax does not work.  You need {% for key,event in events.items %}

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Ah true... I just copy and pasted from the OP but in the documentation it is right...shame on me. Thanks!